# How to get the post of the user using javascript sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating my first facebook app using javascript sdk. In that i can able to post to the user's wall using(FB.api('me/feed', 'post', )).

Now what I need is, when the user accessing my app, it has to show (or list) the post of that user. The code is

```
FB.api('/me/posts',  function(response) {
for (var i=0, l=response.length; i<l; i++) {
var post = response[i];
alert('The value of post is:'+post);
if (post.message) {
  alert('Message: ' + post.message);
} else if (post.attachment && post.attachment.name) {
  alert('Attachment: ' + post.attachment.name);
}
```

}
});

But it is not working. If I remove l=response.length and change the condition as i<5 it is going inside the loop but it gives the value of post is undefined.

I didn't get why it is returning as undefined. It returns same for post.message also.

I am getting the access_token of the user also.

If I want to get the post of my user what code i have to use. Can anyone help me in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Facebook Graph API Explorer to better understand what data you will be receiving. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

You should have `l=response.data.length` and `var post = response.data[i];`. Also, some posts will not have a "message", but will have a "story" instead (mainly posts like "Joe Smith and Tom Someone are now friends."). Make sure you also have the appropriate permissions (e.g. user_status) for the information you're trying to receive.